# Why is nginx giving 200 OK response , even though domain is not hosted on my server ? and how can i fix it?

Tags: nginx, curl

i have hosted example.com on nginx web server at ip 123.123.123.123 and if i use curl with host headers like this from remote machine

```
curl -v -H "Host: example.com" 123.123.123.123/
```

i get

```
curl -v -H "Host: example.com" 123.123.123.123/
*   Trying 123.123.123.123...
* Connected to 123.123.123.123 (123.123.123.123) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.9.9
< Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 01:34:22 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d2a30e617da2fbe890a6855ba4d993bc61450143261; expires=Wed, 14-Dec-16 01:34:21 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=mmdnqp3j4fnf0ph57krl696rb2; path=/
< CF-RAY: 254e67dae06335a8-LHR
```

which is fine as example.com is hosted on server having ip 123.123.123.123

but if i change the host header to any other domain e.g. anyother_domain.com

```
curl -v -H "Host: anyother_domain.com" 123.123.123.123/
```

i get this

```
curl -v -H "Host: anyother_domain.com" 123.123.123.123/
*   Trying 123.123.123.123...
* Connected to 123.123.123.123 (123.123.123.123) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: anyother_domain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.9.9
< Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 01:30:29 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 612
< Last-Modified: Sat, 12 Dec 2015 16:03:23 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "566c454b-264"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

here is my **nginx.conf** file

```
worker_processes 4;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
        include  mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        sendfile on;
        gzip on;
        charset utf-8;

include /usr/local/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

**default.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  123.123.123.123;

charset utf-8;
}
```

**example.com.conf**

```
server {
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return       301 http://example.com$request_uri;
    access_log  /dev/null;
}

server {
server_name  example.com;
}
```

1. Why is this happening ?
   i mean why is server giving 200 OK status even though the domain is not hosted at my server ?
2. how can i fix this ? 
   i mean how can i not give 200 OK status and throw some other header response code ?

Comment: You have directed your first example at CloudFlare. Where did you direct the second one?

Comment: @MichaelHampton i dont own or operate second domain which is anyother_domain.com its just anyother domain which is not hosted at my server while exmaple.com uses cloudflare and it is hosted at my server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is answer: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

*Why is this happening ? i mean why is server giving 200 OK status even though the domain is not hosted at my server ?*

> [Usually] nginx tests only the request’s header field “Host” to
>   determine which server the request should be routed to. If its value
>   does not match any server name, or the request does not contain this
>   header field at all, then nginx will route the request to the default
>   server for this port. In the configuration above, the default server
>   is the first one — which is nginx’s standard default behaviour.

*how can i fix this ? i mean how can i not give 200 OK status and throw some other header response code ?*

> If requests without the “Host” header field should not be allowed, a
>   server that just drops the requests can be defined:
>
> server {
>       listen      80;
>       server_name "";
>       return      444; }
>
> Here, the server name is set to an empty string that will match requests without the “Host” header field, and a
>   special nginx’s non-standard code 444 is returned that closes the
>   connection.

Or try this for all 'default' requests

```
server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    server_name "";
    return      444;
}
```

Comment: yes, this is what i wanted, i added new server block and made it default and now all non existent domains are being refused., thanks i really appreciate it.

Comment: Or you could serve the "it works" page, which is what the configuration did as shipped by Debian.

Comment: yes, but for some reason on my other box, all non existed domains was giving 301 to my main domain , which is causing more trouble, so blocking is best way for me., maybe www to non www redirect server block was acting as default server.